# json.loads is loading an array of json objects as characters

Tags: python, json

I have the code

```
with open(filtered_aws_logs_path) as input:
    for i, line in enumerate(input):
        obj = json.loads("\"" + line[11:-7] + "\"")
        print("response: " + str(i))
        print(obj)
        for json_item in obj:
            print(json_item)
        break
```

The object loads fine into json and when i print it with `print(obj)` it looks like:

```
[{"ip":"66.102.8.203","sg_user_id":7018833,"sg_event_id":"GxXXe3daQAq09ed5p-eprQ","sg_message_id":"b6eFR8T0Qqqz74USEIcbtQ.filter0005p3mdw1-17016-5AA04C0C-E.0","useragent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)","event":"open","marketing_campaign_name":"Test Campaign","email":"emailer@gmail.com","asm_group_id":9611,"timestamp":1520527974,"marketing_campaign_id":2559395,"category":[]}]
```

but when I try and iterate over the array (in this case there's only 1 object) it just prints out the characters line by line. So the beginning of `print(json_item)` is

```
[
{
"
i
p
"
:
"
6
6
```

What is going on here

Comment: What's going on with `"\"" + line[11:-7] + "\""` there? Are you turning your JSON string into a JSON string? (Which means the decoded result would be a string, not an array or object.) What exactly is `line[11:-7]` on its own?

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is still a JSON string. Decode it again with `obj = json.loads(obj)`. For some reason your logs have double encoded JSON.